# Error: PineconeClient: Project name not set, v0.0.10

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api, gpt-4, langchain

Downloaded GitHub - [mayooear/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain:](https://github.com/mayooear/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain) GPT4 & LangChain Chatbot for large PDF docs

When I try to run the app, I get following error

```
PineconeClient: Error getting project name: TypeError: fetch failed

error - [Error: PineconeClient: Project name not set. Call init() first.] {
page: ‘/api/chat’
}
```

My node version is node -v
v18.15.0
Pinecone version is
`“@pinecone-database/pinecone”: “^0.0.10”,`

It seems it is due to issue of fetch() which is an experimental feature. How to disable fetch() and use node-fetch()

Answer (score 0):

I updated the version to 0.0.12 in the package.json file, i.e. “@pinecone-database/pinecone”: “^0.0.12”

This fixed the problem for me.